# How to implement push notification if iPad apps is uploaded to goMax store instead of app store

Tags: ios

I want to implement push notification on my iPad app but availability of app is out of Apple Store.
Can we implement push notification on ipad app for non Apple Store?

what is exact process to implement push notification in case of if your app will not go to apple store?

Answer (score 0):

Your app does not need to be on the app store. All you need is to integrate the Parse iOS SDK into your project:
https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide

This is how you register for notifications:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) 
{
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                         categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

This is how you send a push:

```
    NSMutableArray *channels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
    [push setChannels:channels]; // Set your channels somewhere
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSDictionary *data = @{@"alert":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have a new service request from %@", appDelegate.user[@"name"]],@"badge":@1,@"push_type":@"Request",@"sound":@"default"};
    [push setData:data];
    [push sendPushInBackground];
```